# Emacs のコード中 name_list_element を mark している箇所が見つからない

Tags: emacs, gc

Emacs のソースコードを読みながら、構造を勉強しながら、いじっています。

Emacs のソースコードで、`src/xterm.h` 内 `struct x_display_info` の定義に、

```c
  /* This is a cons cell of the form (NAME . FONT-LIST-CACHE).  */
  Lisp_Object name_list_element;
```

という部分があります。

GC の際にはこの Lisp_Object も mark してやる必要があると思うのですが、その処理が見つかりません。どこで mark してるのでしょうか?
具体的には、

```c
mark_object (dpyinfo->name_list_element);
```

か、またはその代わりの呼び出しがどこかにあるはず、と考えています。

ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

私が見ているコードは
https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs
ですが、教えていただけるなら、リリース版でも開発版でも何でも構いません。

emacs の bug report 先に投げてみることも考えましたが、単なる疑問であって何か症状が起きているわけではないので、そちらには投げていません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [ここ](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/xterm.c#L12551)で `dpyinfo->name_list_element = Fcons (display_name, Qnil);` として cons cell を作成していて、[Fcons function](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/alloc.c#L2734) で `memset (new->gcmarkbits, 0, sizeof new->gcmarkbits);` としています。

Comment: 何を探しているかが不明瞭で失礼しました。質問を修正しました。
実際の bit 操作ではなく、それを呼び出している箇所、つまり `mark_object (dpyinfo->name_list_element);` のようなコードがどこかにあるはず、と思っていて、それを探しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

見つけましたので自己回答します。

`src/alloc.c` に以下の関数があります。

```c
static void
compact_font_caches (void)
{
  struct terminal *t;

  for (t = terminal_list; t; t = t->next_terminal)
    {
      Lisp_Object cache = TERMINAL_FONT_CACHE (t);
      /* Inhibit compacting the caches if the user so wishes.  Some of
         the users don't mind a larger memory footprint, but do mind
         slower redisplay.  */
      if (!inhibit_compacting_font_caches
          && CONSP (cache))
        {
          Lisp_Object entry;

          for (entry = XCDR (cache); CONSP (entry); entry = XCDR (entry))
            XSETCAR (entry, compact_font_cache_entry (XCAR (entry)));
        }
      mark_object (cache);
    }
}
```

ここで、`TERMINAL_FONT_CACHE` は `src/termhooks.h` で

```c
#define TERMINAL_FONT_CACHE(t)                                              \
  (t->type == output_x_window ? t->display_info.x->name_list_element : Qnil)
```

と定義されています。
従って、上記コード中の

```c
      mark_object (cache);
```

の部分が私の探していたものでした。